# Dynamically set the view base type for a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, spark-view-engine

Is it possible to dynamically set the view base type for a partial 
view?

I'm doing a lot of dynamic page generation, using custom `IViewFolder` 
and `IViewFile` implementations, and need to set a specific base type 
for certain views...it's not a problem injecting the correct block, I 
just need to know what block to inject.

I've tried:

```
<use pageBaseType=”MyCustomViewType” />
```

at the top of the partial view, but it doesn't get picked up...is that 
the right syntax? Is it even possible...?

Thanks in advance,

Kieron

Comment: As far as I understand partial views (< use file=""/>) are compiled into the main view and do not have their own page/base type. If you need this, make convention to use <viewdata partialModel="type" />; - i.e. specific variable to be passed to partial; this can be of any type.

Comment: That sounds like it could work, are there any examples floating about that you know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer to this was no!